# Extract specific data from PowerShell output

Tags: powershell

I need to get the specific value from powershell output. I need to get the numeric values in poewershell only.

`$result =WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining`
[image: Output]

Comment: Why not use a builtin PowerShell cmdlet for this instead of WMIC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using [`wmic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) you can use a PowerShell built-in cmdlet to query WMI and CIM:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Battery).EstimatedChargeRemaining
```

See [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.2) for Official Documentation.